# Marshalling C-style array of LPWSTR to managed string[] using pInvoke

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, pinvoke

I'd like to call an unmanaged method that allocates memory, creates an array of `LPWSTR`s, and returns it to managed code. I'd like to avoid in/out parameters and writing code to manage memory and variable scopes as much as possible so I decided I would rely on using `CoTaskMemAlloc` and let the marshaller automagically clean up after me.

Here's what I have (a modified version of a p/invoke tutorial method on MSDN):

```
extern "C" DLL1_API LPWSTR *TestArrayOfStrings(_In_ int count)
{
    STRSAFE_LPWSTR temp = NULL;
    wchar_t * ppStrArray[10] = { NULL };
    const size_t alloc_size = sizeof(wchar_t *) * 10;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        temp = (STRSAFE_LPWSTR)CoTaskMemAlloc(alloc_size);

        if (i % 2 == 0)
            StringCchCopy(temp, alloc_size, L"0123456789");
        else
            StringCchCopy(temp, alloc_size, L"9876543210");

        CoTaskMemFree(ppStrArray[i]);
        ppStrArray[i] = temp;
    }
    count = 10;

    return ppStrArray;
}
```

and on the managed side:

```
[DllImport("Dll1.Windows.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
public static extern string[] TestArrayOfStrings(out int count);
```

As you can see I've tried to use additional attributes but the marshaller just doesn't seem to like it--I keep getting "Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination." I am trying to maintain typing as an array of `LPWSTR`s and would like to avoid `SAFEARRAY`, for which marshalling is marked obsolete.

Comment: SizeParamIndex doesn't work on a return value.  You'd need void Test(out int count, [MarshalAs...] out string[] array).  Or a safe array, it is not obsolete.

Comment: @HansPassant what would you consider the "least effort" method of getting a string array of unknown size back from a C++ method? It would be nice if I could just allocate memory on the managed heap in C++ and return a char ** and the resulting string[] gets automatically GC'd.

Comment: That's not possible of course.  If you don't know the size then you don't know when to stop reading elements.

Comment: @HansPassant got it. I'll try your first suggestion and see if it works for me. By the way, the safe array itself is not obsolete, but if I use the `MarshalAsAttribute` and specify safe array, it tells me that marshalling safe arrays may not be supported in future releases.

Comment: @HansPassant I was able to do this with `(out int count, [MarshalAs...][In][Out] ref string[] array)` but I couldn't get it to work with any combinatoin using `out string[]`. Is that possible?

Comment: @HansPassant Never mind, got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slightly modified code, but the signature was what was important. This method assigns a string value (the third parameter) to the first element of the uninitialized out array passed in.

```
[DllImport("Dll1.Windows.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void TestArrayOfStrings(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr, SizeParamIndex = 1)] [Out] out string[] test, 
        out int size, string someString);

extern "C" DLL1_API void TestArrayOfStrings(wchar_t ***strings, int *size, wchar_t *someString){
    const size_t alloc_size = 64; 
    STRSAFE_LPWSTR temp = (STRSAFE_LPWSTR)CoTaskMemAlloc(alloc_size);
    StringCchCopy(temp, alloc_size, someString);
    *strings = (wchar_t **)CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(wchar_t));
    *strings[0] = temp;
    *size = 1;
}
```